# parsing and looping through json data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have been working on this code for some time now and have researched on various solutions on how to solve it, but i have found none.

I am getting the following json data:

```
{"id":"4","name":"bugatti","details":"the bugatti v8 simplly the best","seats":"2","status":"0","image"
:"","category":"sedean"}{"id":"5","name":"bently","details":"the bently the best of the best","seats"
:"5","status":"0","image":"","category":"SUV"}
```

I'm having trouble parsing that json data which I get from the jquery ajax $.post request as shown below:

```
$.post('response.php',
    {
        task    : 'fleet'
    },
    function(data)
    {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(data , function (key,value)
        {
            console.log(value);
        });
        console.log(data.id);
    }
).error(
    function()
    {
    }
).success(

);
```

Here is the response.php data:

```
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'fleet')
{
$car = new Cars();

$fleet = $car->getAll();

foreach( $car->data() as $cars )
{
    echo json_encode($cars);
}   
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: because you have multiple json objects that are not properly dealt with, instead of your foreach loop, just do `echo json_encode($car->data());`

Comment: i tried that and it does not return any json objects when i display the data in the console

Comment: What appears when you go to response.php manually through the browser? (of course you'll need to quickly change post to get. so you can see it)

Comment: Improved language and format

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

You can also add `dataType: 'json'` to your $.post function.

```
// making sure we pass the header for the json output
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// if $car->data() (is the array, just encode it to json)
echo json_encode($car->data());
```

I ran some examples with your code (without the ajax)

```
var data = '{"id":"4","name":"bugatti","details":"the bugatti v8 simplly the best"}';
data = $.parseJSON(data);

$.each(data , function (key,value)
{
   console.log(value);
});


// key will output id, name, details..
// value will output (what is below)
```

output :

```
 4
 bugatti
 the bugatti v8 simplly the best
```

**(remove `value.id` and just say `value`)** 
If you wanted to confirm the param, you can easily do

```
 if (key == 'id')
```

Comment: thanks its working as i'm not getting any more errors but now i'm now not getting any data when use the console.log function but i'm getting the json data from the database with no parsing errors.